# Project Showcase '14 is coming to Arduino Stack Exchange! (Updated 3/19/14)

Tags: discussion, events

> [image]

Its been a month since launch and we have had a fair bit of Q&A. We have solved a fair number of problems, and now, its time to see where that has gotten you and us! 
To celebrate 10 years of Arduino, we are proud to announce the *first event ever* on Arduino Stack Exchange.

> [image]
>
> <sub>The logo is a derivative of the Arduino Community Logo licensed under Creative Commons license CC-SA-BY-NC 3.0</sub>

Get your boards and soldering equipment out, dig out the ICs and resistors. The first Arduino Stack Exchange contest is just round the corner. We will be looking for interesting projects that are built using Arduinos. The contest is aimed towards sharing, discussing and providing feedback on projects that you and other members are working on. 
There may be a surprise in store as well for the best* submission. 
To make it a huge success, we need your help! Spread the word, tell your friends and colleagues. The more people that participate, the more fun its going to be! 
Keep an eye on this post. More details coming soon.

### Details:

- The prize is an **official Stack Exchange t-shirt** (Provided by Pops)
- Limit two entries per person. If more than two are provided, only the first two will be considered.
- Clones *are* allowed.
- Projects for consideration will be accepted through **March 29th, 2014 at 4:00 UTC.** The question will still remain open in case someone wants to show off their project they made on Arduino Day 2014.

### The rest of the details will be posted on the 23rd in a post on main.

---

<sub>This is being organized by Peter R Bloomfield, Annonomous Person, Sachleen and AsheeshR.</sub>

<sub>*The winner will be decided at the discretion of the event organizers. The event organizers (obviously) cannot win.</sub>

<sub>The logo is a derivative of the Arduino Community Logo licensed under Creative Commons license CC-SA-BY-NC 3.0</sub>

Comment: Does the project have to be something we build from scratch starting on the 23rd?

Comment: @TheGuy Nope. You can build it whenever, just submissions are open on the 23rd.

Comment: The [contest post](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/876/project-showcase-14) and updated [meta post](http://meta.arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/171/project-showcase-14-detailed-information) are now up.