# Project Showcase '14: Detailed Information

Tags: discussion, events

> [image]

To celebrate 10 years of Arduino, we are proud to start the first event ever on Arduino Stack Exchange. The **[Project Showcase '14](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/876/)** is finally here! In case you missed it, see the [earlier post](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/q/153/65). We hope you are ready ;-)

This post covers all the information not covered on main. TL;DR is that participate as you would as if this were any other post (within the spirit of the event), and you will be fine.

---

This contest is about sharing and creativity. Your entries may be anything that you may have recently worked on, the complexity or the difficulty level doesnt matter. What matters, is how much effort you put in and how much you enjoyed the process.

#### Rules

- The contest submissions must follow the submission format (available on main).
- Each submission must contain only one project.
- Only first two submissions by a user will be eligible for consideration for the prize.
- No major changes beyond grammar, punctuation, formatting should be made to a post after initial posting. All major changes will be rolled back, and the post will not be considered for the prize.
- The winner will be the submission getting the maximum number of upvotes (downvotes do not count) and will get a Stack Exchange T-shirt*! There will be something for the runner-up as well. The runner-up will be decided at the discretion of the event organizers.
- The event organizers cannot win the event.
- Decisions of the event organizers will be final and binding.

#### Guidelines

- This is about showcase and critique. Post feedback on others' submissions via comments. Suggest improvements and changes. We are here to help each other improve and grow.
- Please keep the environment positive and encouraging for everybody. Any rudeness will not be tolerated, and may lead to disqualification.
- Do not engage in strategic voting or sockpuppeting. These may result in site bans.
- Most importantly, have fun!

Also, don't forget to spread the word! Tell your friends and colleagues. The more people that participate, the more interesting its going to be!

**[Return to main post.](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/876/)**

## Questions & Clarifications

- *Do projects using bare AVRs count?* Official boards, clones, and derivatives that utilize at least the main Arduino library are acceptable for entries. This means your ATTiny with Arduino bootloader is okay, but your ATMega328p running only AVR C or Assembly is not. It must involve Arduino!

---

<sub>This post may be updated during the event. Any major changes will be announced on main.</sub>

<sub>*Certain restrictions may apply. International shipping may take a few weeks.</sub>

<sub>This event is being organized by Peter R Bloomfield, Annonomous Person, Sachleen and AsheeshR.</sub>

<sub>The logo is a derivative of the [Arduino Community Logo](http://arduino.cc/en/Trademark/CommunityLogo) licensed under [Creative Commons license CC-SA-BY-NC 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

What are the **specific** requirements for qualifying as "involving" Arduino?

There is a **LOT** of latitude there.

- What if a project *just* uses the optiboot bootloader?
- What if a project is compiled using [Stino](https://github.com/Robot-Will/Stino)
- What if a project is compiled using the ["Bare GCC"](https://github.com/Robot-Will/Stino/pull/123) Stino option I implemented, which disables most of the default arduino interrupts, and requires that the programmer implements `int main(){}` themselves?
  Note: You *can* still use the `Serial` libraries without the default interrupts via this option. Does that qualify?

I have *lots* of project that are basically what I describe above. Optiboot bootloader, compiled with Stino, the only "arduino" thing I really use is the `Serial` library, and then that's just for debugging purposes. I think I could probably reasonably argue this is within the bounds of the rules, and yet I don't think it's realistically eligible.

- For that matter, what about editing the arduino source files? I could make a project that looks *exactly* like a simple arduino project, that does something completely different by modifying the template folders. That would satisfy the "use the main arduino libraries" requirement. You should probably clarify that the arduino files have to be stock.

---

Realistically, I can't really see this contest even really *working* without any hardware requirements. I think a much better contest would require the use of one of the actual arduino boards.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! We had initially started with only Arduino board based projects, but considering this was the first time and we weren't completely sure of the response, we decided to keep it fairly open. Also, most of the competition was thought of assuming *good faith* on the part of members of our community, which is why the submission criteria are quite flexible. If there is a *next* time, feel completely free to participate in the  organization and formulation of the rules regarding the event.

Answer (score 0):

Another question:

Does adding better pictures (by replacing the existing pictures) count as a "major" change? I'd like to take a better camera to work tomorrow and get better images of the boards in my post.

The images would be substantially the same, just with less blur and glare.

Comment: If they're pretty much the same, sure.